# How to auto-update date field on firebase using ng-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a date field (called: lastUpdate) on a firebase db.

How could I update that field using ng-grid on change from another field (say a separte field called: notes)?

Im using the following code to update my records on edit:

```
var cellEditableTemplate = "<input ng-class=\"'colt' + col.index\" 
ng-input=\"COL_FIELD\" ng-model=\"COL_FIELD\" 
ng-change=\"updateEntity(col,row)\"/>"

$scope.updateEntity = function (col, row) {

        $scope.dblogs.$save(row.entity.$id);

    };
```

***Posted Below is my sample db being used:***

```
uniqueIDajsdljfasdjfajsdf;jasdj
|
|
--->ticket
|       |
|       -->completed: true
|       |
|       -->dateUpdated: "(last activity date/time)"
|       |
|       -->notes:  "need to update logger code today!"
|
---->username: "vr"
```

Comment: Not clear what your example has to do with a date field. There's not enough here to reproduce your attempt.

Comment: Would putting something like `$scope.dblogs[row.entity.$id].lastUpdate = Date.now()` inside of updateEntity help?

Comment: Tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I update my question.  Thanks for the help!